# How to dynamically Change \lhead depending on the page

Tags: header-footer

I have and article document in latex. In this document, I have set `\lhead` in the header of doc. But as my doc is about many themes, I was wondering if I could change `\lhead` contain dynamically?

Comment: You should use the proper mark interface instead of setting the headers by hand.

Comment: @Johannes_B please explain a bit more how to do this.

Comment: Use `\lhead{\leftmark}` (or rather the modern form which is described in the `fancyhdr` manual, but that i forgot now).